# Compiling desktop JavaScript code on Java, Android app, Windows, Linux, Mac-os

Tags: javascript, java, android, cross-platform, desktop

I'm old, outdated programming skills, and know very little about Java and Javascript except they are very different.

Objective: I wish to develop an ARM hardware product that uses a subset of desktop JavaScript as it's user development target for commercial programs, and on other systems as android apps (once ported), Java programs and on desktop Windows, Linux and Mac OS systems. Reuse of the same code. I understand Javascript is based on a subset of common embedded Java API's.  JavaScript provides a regularly supported small foot print engine that can be bought in.

Another separate objective for the other platforms, is to support programs using the full desktop JavaScript specification.

Question:  Is it possible to set up Java and Java under android, to natively compile desktop javascript (as c++ canbe setup under C, and C under Forth)?

I realise this is an unconventional way of doing this, but adds flexibility with access to one code base.

Comment: What do you mean set up java to natively compile javascript? Java itself is not even natively compiled.

Comment: Java ships with a JavaScript engine. It was called Rhino before Java 8 and Nashorn since 8 - they reimplemented the engine. I don't know if it's shipped on Android

Comment: I think I have missed the blindily obviouse.  It would be simpler to produce a Java bytecode executable from JavaScript and convert to the new android Dalvik bytecode (which is now compiled to machine code in Android 5.0).  Any tools for this, and compatibility frameworks, to compile JavaScript to these two bytecodes?

Comment: To speed things up I am aiming to avoid Javascript engine interpretation where possible.